# How to Access contacts list from button, and then view contact

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to make an app that, when a button is pressed, the contact list is pulled up, and when a contact is selected, it opens the contact for viewing. Currently, I am able to pull up the contact list, but once I select the name, it goes back to the button screen. Any help here? Here is my code

```
public class TestStuff extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button contacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bContacts);
        contacts.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);   


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start an activity for result using the `startActivityForResult` method, it's suppose to go back to your previous activity with the desired result, in this case I guess the result would be the contact name you have chosen, I don't have much experience with the contacts API but I guess that there is a method to pull all the data you need regarding a single contact.